# Android number of satellites problem

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to obtain the number of satellites used in fix but it keeps returning 0.

```
GpsStatus gps = mlocManager.getGpsStatus(null);
    Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = gps.getSatellites();
    Iterator satI = sats.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while(satI.hasNext()){
        GpsSatellite gpssatellite = (GpsSatellite) satI.next();
        if (gpssatellite.usedInFix()){
        count++;
        }
    }
```

I am using the code in

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
```

I know that there is one more question like this on stackoverflow but I tried the code an it still returns 0. I tried on emulator and Nexus S.